# Dynamic data not rendering in prerender-spa-plugin

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I use prerender-spa-plugin in vue.js app for rendering html
but it can't render dynamic data.
when prerender-spa-plugin complete rendering
created html file only contains some html code not showing any dynamic data

## Method

[image: Method]

## Mounted

[image]

## prerender-spa-plugin Configuration

[image]

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 0):

Adding the headless option solve the problem for me:

```
 renderer: new Renderer({
    injectProperty: '__PRERENDER_INJECTED',
    renderAfterTime: 5000,

   // Other puppeteer options.
   // (See here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions)
    headless: false // Display the browser window when rendering. Useful for debugging.
})
```